# Pegar todas as classes de um determinado Package que está no classpath

Tags: java, reflexão

Eu estou precisando pegar todas as classes de um determinado *package*, eu vi alguns códigos que fazem isso, porém, só pega as classes que fazem parte do projeto em si, basicamente não utiliza *reflection* e sim faz uma busca por arquivos `.class` no diretório, no meu caso, eu preciso pegar os `.class` de um jar que faz parte do meu projeto.

Algo como:

```
List<Class> clazz = ReflectionUtil.getClassFromPackage("org.springframework.util");

List<Class> clazz = ReflectionUtil.getClassFromPackage("com.meuprojeto.meupacotebase");
```

Eu já tentei:

http://mike.shannonandmike.net/2009/09/02/java-reflecting-to-get-all-classes-in-a-package/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519626/how-to-get-all-classes-names-in-a-package

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection

Falaram dessa biblioteca http://github.com/ronmamo/reflections

mas tem o seguinte código:

```
 Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.project");

 Set<Class<? extends SomeType>> subTypes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(SomeType.class);
```

Ora, eu preciso pegar a lista de classes, eu não quero especificar o tipo de classe que preciso

Eu penso que isso seria ou deveria ser básico com o *reflection* do Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar a biblioteca *Reflections* de uma forma não usual, mas é possível:

```java
//lista as classes do pacote "com.google", incluindo os subpacotes
Reflections r = new Reflections(
        "com.google", 
        new SubTypesScanner(false),
        ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader()
    );
Set<Class<?>> classes = r.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);

//exibe a lista classes
for (Class<?> c : classes) {
    System.out.println(c.getName());
}
```

O parâmetro `new SubTypesScanner(false) permite a listagem de classes através de`Object.class`, isto é, classes que não tem herança explícita. Caso contrário essas classes seriam ignoradas.

O parâmetro `ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader()` lista todas as classes do *Class Loader* atual, caso contrário seriam listadas apenas as classes do projeto/jar atual.

Somente tenha cuidado se alguma classe que não puder ser carregada (talvez por falta de uma dependência), senão você acaba com uma exceção como essa:

```java
Exception in thread "main" org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not get type for name org.dom4j.xpath.DefaultNamespaceContext
    at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:378)
    at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forNames(ReflectionUtils.java:387)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.getSubTypesOf(Reflections.java:338)
    at snippet.ListClasses.main(ListClasses.java:15)
```

---

Outra opção seria fazer tudo manualmente, isto é, você pode olhar o `classpath` na variável de ambiente e percorrer todos os diretórios procurando por arquivos `.class` e jars que contenham as classes que você precisa.

Sinceramente, não vale a pena. Se não quiser usar uma biblioteca para facilitar o trabalho, adicione algumas restrições no projeto para facilitar a listagem das classes.

Comment: Cara, muito bom, era exatamente isso que eu queria, deu certo, eu não tinha conseguido por esse detalhe que vc falou new SubTypesScanner(false), bela explicação, mais uma vez, muito obrigado pela ajuda!